# Authenticated User entry are not saved in Database

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
@objc func registerButtonClicked()
{
```

//After Firebase is configured this is called

```
    guard let email = emailTextField.text else {
        alertBox(title: "Error", message: "All fields are mandatory")
        return }

    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }

    guard let name = nameTextField.text else { return }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (data, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error.debugDescription)
            print("Error occurred")
        } else
        {
            print("Data -- >\(String(describing: data))")
            self.saveDataInFirebase(name: name, password: password, email: email)
```

//here the data is saved in authentication table in firebase so next step //was to save its detail in db in json

```
        }
    }
}
func saveDataInFirebase(name: String, password: String, email: String)
{

    let userData = ["name" : name, "email" : email]
    print("name \(name) --- Email \(email)")
```

// printing the details to be saved in DB

```
    let firebaseRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://chatdemo1-d3423.firebaseio.com/")
    firebaseRef.updateChildValues(userData) { (error, dbRef) in
        if error != nil{
            print("------------------")
            print(error.debugDescription)
            print("----------------------")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Data Saved Successfully")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your codes as text instead of an image. Also you should include your database structure and database security rules (as Text)

Comment: The signIn method I used is the normal sign in way Since the authenticated user entries are stored in db when I look for auth users but the entry is not saved in database where we see the users in son format

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is probably not what you want to use as it will overwrite your entire Firebase each time it's run.

The reason for that is you're not writing data to a child node of your Firbase, you are writing it to the main node. This is what's being written:

```
your_firebase //<- this is where you're writing too each time
   email: "some email"
   name:  "some name"
```

my guess is you want to stucture it like this

```
your_firebase
    user_id
      email: "some email"
      name:  "some name"
```

and the code to do that would be

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

func viewDidLoad() {
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    .
    .
    .     
}

func createUser() {
    let email = "some email"
    let password = "some password"
    let name = "some name"
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
        if let x = error { //some fancy error checking
            let err = x as NSError
            switch err.code {
            case AuthErrorCode.emailAlreadyInUse.rawValue:
                print("email in use!")
            default:
                print("unknown error")
            }
        } else {
            guard let user = authResult?.user else { return }
            let uid = user.uid
            let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
            let thisUserRef = usersRef.child(uid)
            thisUserRef.child("email").setValue(email)
            thisUserRef.child("name").setValue(name)
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes the Firebase Rules allows the user permission to write the the users node

Comment: I need to extract the result from auth result that I will get when the user is registered in createUser method is what you trying to tell ?

Comment: https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2519     see this link for my code and console output

Comment: @ShubhamTomar This line *guard let user = authResult?.user else { return }* extracts the authResult, which is a Firebase user object. From there you can obtain the user uid. Once you have that, you can store other information about the user such as their name, favorite food and which posts they are following in a /users/uid node. Try the code in my question as it's tested and does what you want.